# Getting Max value from dataset with redundant rows in R

Tags: r

I have a data set with 3 ids  and a cost. I need to get maximum of this cost if  3 ids repeat in the set
ex:

```
id1 id2 id3  cost
1   100 450  1000
2   678 098  786
3   897 867  7897
1   100 450  1500
```

my output should be

```
id1 id2 id3  cost
2   678 098  786
3   897 867  7897
1   100 450  1500
```

because all 3 ids are the same as 1 and `max(1500,1000) = 1000`

Also, how to obtain minimum of the same set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `summarise_each`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(id1, id2, id3) %>%
   summarise_each(funs(max))
```

---

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, lapply(.SD, max) , by = .(id1, id2, id3)]
```

---

Or using `aggregate` from `base R`

```
aggregate(cost~., df1, FUN = max)
```